# how do you convert a fasta file into an sql table?

Tags: sql, database, fasta

I have a fasta file temp_mart.txt as such:

```
ENSG00000100219|ENST00000005082
MTLLTFRDVAIEFSLEEWKCLDLAQQNLYRDVMLENYRNLFSVGLTVCKPGL
```

And I tried to load it into a table in sql using

```
load data local infile '~/Desktop/temp_mart.txt' into table mart
```

But instead of getting an output like this:

```
+-----------------+------+------+
| ENSG            | ENST |               3UTR |
+-----------------+------+------+
| >ENSG0000010021 | ENST00000005082 |     MTLLTFRDVAIEFSL  |
```

I get this:

```
+-----------------+------+------+
| ENSG            | ENST | 3UTR |
+-----------------+------+------+
| >ENSG0000010021 | NULL | NULL |
| MTLLTFRDVAIEFSL | NULL | NULL |
| EPWNVKRQEAADGHP | NULL | NULL |
| DKFTAMSSHFTQDLL | NULL | NULL |
```

Everything seems to go into the first column. What is the best way to load it into the table so it presents as intended? Do I need to convert it into a csv file first?

Comment: I assume you're using mysql as rdbms. If that is not corect please remove the mysql tag (you can [edit]) I added and replace it with a tag for your specific rdbms. Using the correct tags makes that users that can answer your question are more likely to find it.

Comment: You will have to preprocess the file if you want to use that command. Otherwise, create a script that handles the file properly. As a side note, the fasta file you show us is incorrect (missing '>' at the beggining of the ID) and incomplete (there are more things added to the DB that are in the showed file).

Comment: Why do you need that file in a database? That's not common, it is difficult for the database to manage this kind of information and there are lots of tools to deal with FastA files easily.

Comment: Thank you Rene - I'm not sure how to find out my specific rdbms so I have just removed the MySQL tag

Comment: @ Poshi - how do I create a script that handles the file properly? - do you mean to edit the description of the table?

Comment: Additionally - I require this file in a such a table so I can use a left join to retrieve the 3'UTRs for specific ENSTs from a different table

Comment: So you are not interested in the sequence, but in the proper parsing of the ID line to retrieve ID-contained information?